# Show custom fields from another pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

i have some pages with with custom fields, these custom fields info i will show under my menu by rollover as page description for other pages dynamically.

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_desc', true)
```

these works fine, but only for the current page. i can't get the custom field infos from the other pages. how can i solve this?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way using this function.

But if you know other post id or logic to get it

pass that id to

```
get_post_meta($post_ID, 'page_desc', true)
```

Where $post_ID id is the other post id.

Comment: @efendi Wel Come, Up or accept the comment if it is work for oyu